# Page is reloading when using 'LinkToObject' in amChart Map

Tags: maps, amcharts

What i am currently doing, I am using amChart map along with markers and some of the other charts on same page, i've setup the marker and provide URL whenever user click on particular marker whole screen will reload and values/charts will appear accordingly.

Now my problem is when user select that particular country from Map marker URL will update, rest of the charts are working fine even Map starts to zoom accordingly but when zoom is complete, page is reloading itself with same URL. This thing is continuously going on without stopping, if i remove LinkToObject tag from DataProvider of Chart everything works fine, only map will not zoom itself.

I think you got my point, if you need anything else let me know.

Comment: Can you post your map code and a sample of your data that reproduces this? Preferably as a functional jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, basically i set the URL parameter behind every marker of Map and when user try to click on marker complete page will refresh and map starts to zoom to that particular marker. In this case, when map is zoom it is assuming that marker has been clicked so the code is again starts to refresh page. I've increase the check in the code that if URL is set with any particular parameter it means marker is already selected and when page is loading i've remove URL from that marker. By doing this when there is no URL found on click of marker then technically it will not refresh itself.